# Fatal error: Cannot use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\area\TokenizeAreaPluginBase as TokenizeAreaPluginBase

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, fatal-error

I encountered a fatal error in my Drupal project and need assistance in resolving it. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```php
Fatal error: Cannot use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\area\TokenizeAreaPluginBase as TokenizeAreaPluginBase because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/golden/absolute_you/web/modules/contrib/views_add_button/src/Plugin/views/area/ViewsAddButtonArea.php on line 12
```

I'm unsure how to resolve this issue and would appreciate any guidance or insights.

Answer (score 0):

you just  need to update composer with:

````bash
composer update "drupal/views_add_button" --with-all-dependencies
drush updatedb
drush cache:rebuild```
````